# Как типизировать children в React.js, чтобы можно было передать только свой компонент?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Как типизировать children в React.js, чтобы можно было передать только свой компонент?

Comment: просто берешь и прописываешь свой тип

Comment: Мне нужно передать целый компонент в чилдрен, чтобы нельзя было передавать другие компоненты и теги, как я должен прописать свой тип?

Comment: а как ты обычно прописываешь тип? Добавь пример двух своих компонентов: контейнера и тот который хочешь передавать